# How to get an _id of parent document mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to implement a method in express router, that would delete an embedded document from a parent document by its `_id`.

My code looks like this:

.hbs

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
        <td>{{movie.genre}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    {{# each movie.comments}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{this.author}}</td>
        <td>{{this.comment}}</td>
        <td><a href="comment/delete/{{movie._id}}/{{this._id}}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

I can easily get an _id of my embedded doc (single comment), but I can't get an _id of my parent (movie) doc.

On back-end everything seems to be ok, but I get 404 error, because movie._id is empty so my `link(/movie/comment/delete//58111f46d7cf8730305e1d5c)` doesn't match its pattern in router.

I populate my view with this:

```
Movie.findById(req.params.id).populate('comments').exec(function(err, movie)
```

and render the movie object

Comment: Or is it just possible to find a parent document with sub documents ID?

Comment: You should share your router's code (or part of it) to clarify your question. Also it is impossible to know what's happening if you don't explain how you populate your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the context changes in `#each`, try going up a level:

```
<a href="comment/delete/{{../movie._id}}/{{this._id}}">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Hmmm looks very simple) I'll try it. But I already found a solution. I do magic in my router

Comment: Your answer works! I could do everything with less headache :D I'll mark ur answer as the correct one. Can't believe it was so simple. I keep my link shorter with my solution, but it was hard to write a correct query to find parent doc by child's doc id

Comment: @JavaEvgen yeah, an alternative would have been to run a query to find the movie based on the comment id.